# Why "hwclock -u" is not displaying the time in UTC?

Tags: linux, chrony

```
               Local time: Sat 2022-01-29 23:18:39 CET
           Universal time: Sat 2022-01-29 22:18:39 UTC
                 RTC time: Sat 2022-01-29 22:18:39
                Time zone: Europe/Paris (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no

[root@rhcsa1 ~]# hwclock --get -u
2022-01-29 23:18:53.243325+01:00
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to? The -u flag doesn't set the display timezone it sets the timezone used to interpret the RTC.

Answer (score 1):

The Hardware Clock does not know its timezone, it's just a clock. So if it's not set to UTC, but to some other specific timezone, you have to provide the timezone yourself.

The `-u`, `--utc` option does not tell `hwclock` to display time in UTC. It's just an option to specify that yes, the clock is to be considered UTC, as opposed to `-l`, `--localtime`.

It tells `hwclock` that the time stored inside the Hardware Clock is UTC and thus the correct local time can be calculated and displayed.

If you want `hwclock` to display the UTC time you can achieve it:

```
# TZ=UTC date
Sat Jan 29 22:52:47 UTC 2022
# TZ=UTC hwclock --get --utc
2022-01-29 23:52:50.968087+00:00
```

In my case the Hardware Clock is set to localtime not UTC, so the output does not match when reading it as UTC. In your case it should match. In my case it would also not match with `--localtime` as `TZ` is set to the wrong timezone.

So there is no way to make `hwclock` print the time in UTC if the Hardware Clock is not set to UTC.

---

The man page also explains it:

> -r, --show; --get
> Read the Hardware Clock and print its time to standard output in
> the ISO 8601 format. **The time shown is always in local time, even
> if you keep your Hardware Clock in UTC.**

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it!

Comment: In my < timedatectl > command, the RTC time is set to UTC right? and isn't the rtc the same as hardware clock ?

Comment: @MalekJoumaa yes, but `hwclock` still does not show you what is stored in the rtc raw, it still applies the local time to it like `date` too... it's even mentioned in the manpage, I will add to the answer